# Combining two differential to make into one.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

By using equation 6 and 7 the author formed another differential equation.But I did not understand how he did.

[image: equations]

Comment: it's really just a veryyyyyyy tedious coefficient manipulation.

Comment: I see this as one of those cases where you can try to prove it, if you want, but it would be quite difficult. Instead, maybe you just have to believe that it's true. In studying engineering, there are a lot of such cases.

Comment: Please type all the relevant information as text or MathJax formulas, instead of using a picture

Answer (score 0):

You have a structure 
$$
p_1(D)U+q(D)W=0\\
p_2(D)W-q(D)U=0
$$
with $D$ the derivation operator, $DU=U'$, $D^2U=U''$ etc. and $p(D)$, $q(D)$ the linear operators that are polynomials in $D$.
\begin{align}
p_1(D)&=EI_{zz}D^4-2k^2(2EI_{xx}+EI_{zz})D^2+(k^4EI_{zz}-m\omega^2)I\\
p_2(D)&=EI_{xx}D^4-2k^2(EI_{xx}+2EI_{zz})D^2+(k^4EI_{xx}-m\omega^2)I\\
q(D)&=2k(EI_{xx}+EI_{zz})(D^3-k^2D)
\end{align}

Obviously then one can combine
$$
p_2(D)p_1(D)U=-p_2(D)q(D)W=-q(D)p_2(D)W=-q(D)^2U
$$
so that $[p_1(D)p_2(D)+q(D)^2]U=0$ and similarly $[p_1(D)p_2(D)+q(D)^2]W=0$. As $p_k$ are both even polynomials and $q$ is odd, the above combination is again an even polynomial, that is, only even order derivatives occur in the resulting equation.

Comment: How you written the second set of equations

Comment: I understood but my differential equations are not this simple.

Comment: Yes, they are that simple. The other step that was taken was to rescale the independent parameter so that the powers of $k$ are distributed differently.